# AWS - Changing Security Group Rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've been asked to edit some a webpage on a AWS deployed app.

Unfortunately the developer who set this up is MIA which means I can't ask them which ec2 (or wherever else) the site is hosted, to access the files and change them.

I want to check a couple of instances but can't ssh onto them as their security group doesn't allow it.

If I were to change the security group of some instances could it potentially cause problems with applications already running?

(and a potential follow up question - I think the application is .NET, if I were to edit one of the files would the application need restarting?)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: In general, if you change security groups for an instance to allow a broader range of connections than was previous, the application's functionality should not be affected (but new security issues might be introduced). If however the change entails "tightening" the security, i.e.  blocking communication to specific addresses or ports that were previously possible, naturally the application's behavior might be affected (or might not - it really depends on the application and its uses).

Answer (score 1):

If you are changing security groups by relaxing the rules - i.e. making them more lenient, it is unlikely to affect an application.

Putting more restrictive rules *may* impact an application, so be  careful.

If you need to get in there and figure out what is going on, I would temporaryily open up any ports you need access to, but restrict it to your own IP address - and then once you have investigated, you can close that hole back up.